# How do I scan my files and know they are not infected in Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, security, malware

Im consolidating my data onto an encrypted partition and would like peace of mind that nothing lingers like steganography or code execution things, is there a method to searching for possible steganography or malware in these "usually" benign, but many, files?  Maybe somebody can explain the science behind doing this :)

Comment: The point of steganography is that you can't tell it's there. Therefore you can't scan for it

Comment: I'm not sure you know what steganography is. Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography.

Comment: thanks guys, you're likely right I don't know it is.  I'm trying to learn the ideas of this concept, whether my files will execute code I didn't know was there if I didn't somehow know it was there.  I have a motherload of music, pics, videos I wanna make sure are clean before I store the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of products (free and otherwise) that will run in linux and scan for viruses, but we generally don't recommend products here.  [Clamav](http://www.clamav.net/) is a free favorite.

Looking for unknown steganography is like trying to decrypt something without the decryption key. You might get lucky, but probably not. If they didn't want it hidden, they wouldn't have used steganography.

Comment: If you want more explanation than that, you need to ask in the security/encryption area, but they won't like your question as phrased any more than they do here.

Comment: Hey thank you for the information all.